# Mysql condition with same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure.

Table - Info

```
| day | hour | data |
| 2   |  3   |  A   |
| 3   |  5   |  B   |
| 4   |  1   |  B   |
```

Now I want to write a query to select the data as 
from day 2 hour 3 onwards to day 4 hour 1.

So I have written query something like below.

```
select * from Info 
where day >= 2 and hour >= 3 and day <= 4 and hour <= 1
```

But problem here is that it is comparing time of day 2 with hour 1 also.

Can anyone please help me out? I am stuck here.

Comment: It is noteworthy that the moment you use functions/expressions on the column in `WHERE` clause, the query becomes [non-sargeable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/2469308). So, if performance is the criteria, you should look for solutions which are able to use indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `day` and `hour` mean what their name is then you can do it by converting everything to hours:

```
select * from Info 
where (day * 24 + hour) between (2 * 24 + 3) and (4 * 24 + 1)
```

To be more accurate the condition should be:

```
((day - 1) * 24 + hour) between ((2 - 1) * 24 + 3) and ((4 - 1) * 24 + 1)
```

but this does not affect the results.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CXGeMapS9ggdQB7LeQG3b/0).
Results:

```
| day | hour | data |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 2   | 3    | A    |
| 3   | 5    | B    |
| 4   | 1    | B    |
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Now I did it

Answer (score 0):

One option could be that you do a subquery and first select all records `day >= 2 and hour >= 3` and then in in the outer query put `day <= 4 and hour <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

A *performant* way (query which can utilize indexes (if defined)) will be considering three exclusive scenarios.

First scenario is that the day lies between (non-inclusive) the given start and end day values.

Second scenario would be that the day is same as the given start day value, and the hour value is `>=` to the given start hour value.

Third scenario would be that the day is same as the given end day value, and the hour value is `<=` to the given end hour value.

```
select * from Info 
where 
  (day > 2 AND day < 4)   /* First Scenario */
  OR 
  (day = 2 AND hour >= 3)  /* Second Scenario */
  OR 
  (day = 4 AND hour <= 1)  /* Third Scenario */
```

For good performance, please define the following **Composite Index** `(day, hour)`

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CXGeMapS9ggdQB7LeQG3b/1)

**Result**

```
| day | hour | data |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 2   | 3    | A    |
| 3   | 5    | B    |
| 4   | 1    | B    |
```

Comment: Thank you. this is also useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on forpas's feedback

```
select * from info where ((day*24)+hour) between 51 and 97
```

Comment: So from day = 1 and hour = 20 and to day = 5 and hour = 1 `between 120 and 51 will return nothing`

Comment: Thanks for catching that!